# On virtual machines like JVM and CLR, is there something similar to an operating system, which provides programming APIs?

Tags: jvm, virtual-machine, clr

JVM and CLR are virtual machines. Similarly to bare metal computer machines,  they provide virtual machine languages.

On real computer machines, we have operating systems, which provide system calls and APIs. For example the famous book Advanced Programming Unix Environment describes the APIs provided by Unix and Linux. Windows, however, provide different APIs.

On top of virtual machines like JVM and CLR, is there something which

- plays the role of an operating system, and
- provides programming APIs?

If there is nothing playing the role of an OS  on virtual machines like JVM and CLR, what provides programming APIs (such as those in Java, C#, ...) similar to OS APIs?

Note: I am asking about VMs and on top of them, instead of what is underlying them. Do VMs not run some virtual OS on top of them?  If there is no, why is there no such a need?

Thanks.

Comment: Both of those VMs run on an underlying OS, don't they? You can't just install either of them on a system with a blank, formatted hard drive and run anything. (Go ahead, try. We'll wait.)

Comment: I am asking about VMs and on top of them, instead of underlying them. Do VMs not run some virtual OS on top of them?

Comment: Yes, they do. You mentioned the Java and CLR VMs, and I specifically said *both of those VMs run on an underlying OS*.  What part of that isn't clear?

Comment: What you don't answer is: Is there a virtual OS running on top of the VMs? The VMs are virtualization of bare metal machines, and what are virtualization of real OS running on top of the VMs? If there is no, why is there no such a need?

Comment: No. There is an OS running *beneath* them, which provides the underlying functionality. For instance, the CLR running on Windows routes to the underlying functionality of the WIndows OS, and when running on Linux routes to the functionality in the Linux kernel. You're confusing Java/CLR VMs with *computer VMs*, which create virtualized hardware. They're not the same thing.

Comment: Thanks. What are "computer VMs", for example? Wikipedia article?

Comment: It is a game of semantics.  But for all intentions, JVM and the CLR are the operating system for the virtual machines they implement.  They do stuff that a real OS never does, but ought to, like making code architecture independent, providing a broad well defined type system,  removing the drudgery of memory management, making it simple to modularize code.  The real OS got stuck at supporting C code, but could not move beyond without getting too implementation-specific.  This was tried before, the Lisp machines are notable.  But they didn't last, they fell victim to less-is-better.

Answer (score 2):

There are [two kinds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine#Process_virtual) of virtual machines: system virtual machines and process virtual machines. System virtual machines provide a virtualization of  complete instructions sets including user-mode instructions and kernel-mode instructions and therefore they can run operating systems. Process virtual machines virtualizes user-mode instructions and, usually, some system calls (such as those for managing threads, memory, and files) and therefore can only run applications or processes. That is, on top of a single process virtual machine a single app or process can run. The JVM and CLR are process virtual machines.

While in theory it is indeed possible to develop an [OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) to run on a process virtual machine, this is practically not useful because the performance of the programs that will run on that OS will be terrible due to the excessive layering in software.

Generally, system and process virtual machines themselves are not considered to be operating systems. However, process virtual machines do not necessarily require an OS to run on and may run on a bare-metal computer. The [.NET Micro Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Micro_Framework#cite_ref-13) is an example of such VM. [Such VMs are sometimes called operating systems](http://www.tinyclr.com/). Some [virtual ISAs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_processor) or a subset thereof have been implemented completely in hardware similar to x86 and ARM. One could develop operating systems to run on them. They are almost never used in industry because of their low performance.

Answer (score 1):

An "operating system" is a a large, fuzzy ball of hairs. You got the hal, kernel, userspace... do we count some userspace libraries (typically libc) too?

With squinting you can find some comparable concepts in the JVM/JRE but generally a JVM runs on top of a bona-fide operating system and thus does not reimplement all aspects and instead simply provides platform-independent abstractions over facilities that you can find on almost all systems.

For example these days `Thread` *usually* is just java representation of native OS threads, but a JVM *could* choose to implement thread scheduling in userspace, and in sun's JVM did back during 1.1 times and some other JVMs still do today.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer this from the perspective of Java since I have no in-depth knowledge of .Net.  I would assume, however that the CLR and JVM are similar from this point of view.

Let's start with an operating system.  The purpose of this is to abstract away the hardware specific interfaces as well as providing a runtime environment for processes.

The OS uses device drivers to provide a uniform interface to similar devices (like the processor, memory, disk drives, network cards and so on).  The OS uses system calls to allow user-level code to interact with these devices.  If you wrote code in C you will call 'open' then 'read' and 'write' to the device before calling 'close'.  The 'ioctl' (IO control) system call is also used a lot for device control.  Each OS provides a standard set of these system calls (you can run Linux on an Intel or ARM processor, but you have the same set of system calls for each distro).  Incidentally, this is also how Docker works by using a standard set of system calls to enable containers to be moved from one platform to another without problem.

The OS also provides the ability to run multiple processes simultaneously.  With newer, multi-core machines this really can happen in parallel but the OS also uses scheduling to share a CPU between multiple processes or threads.  By switching processes or threads very quickly this gives the impression that things are happening simultaneously, even on a single processor.

Now let's look at the JVM, which is a user-level process (from the OS point of view so just like any other user application).  This has been designed to abstract away CPU and operating specific functionality from the Java application.  The bytecodes generated by the Java compiler do not contain any system calls.  If you look at the bytecode instruction set (defined in the Java Virtual Machine Specification) you will find that the instructions provide many familiar low-level features such as loading a register, bit manipulation and so on.  In addition, there are many instructions that are higher level and relate more specifically to Java; things like invokestatic that invokes a static method on a class, monitorenter. monitorexit for locking, newarray and so on.

The JVM takes these bytecodes and converts them from a CPU- and OS-independent form (that of a Virtual Machine) into the instructions for the specific CPU architecture and OS that the JVM is running on.  In some cases this can be a one-to-one mapping (for things like bitwise operators), but can often be much more complex and involve the use of system calls to open files, access network interfaces, etc.  The JVM also uses the OS to deal with threads created by the application.  In the very early days of Java operating systems like Windows 95 did not have the concept of threads within a process so the JVM had to provide it's own implementation (this was called green threads and performed pretty badly).

To summarise the JVM takes the platform neutral bytcodes of the class files it is executing and converts them to the apprporiate native CPU instructions and system calls to make the application run.  The JVM does not provide any traditional OS services, it just uses them.